# Creating a 3 Form C# application.

Tags: c#

A project that I received from school has simple instructions: Create a working 3 form C# application. I decided to create a form which will let the user choose from 3 different options (In this case: 1 ticket, 2 tickets, and 3 tickets). Then it will switch to a 2nd form and also let the user choose from 3 options (In this case: 1 bag of popcorn, A large soda, and a bag of chips). The Problem I am having is when it tries to display the total cost its always ends up being 0. I would really appreciate any help.
Code:

**Form1:**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
namespace WongGregory9_part3ThreeForms
{
    public partial class movieForm : Form
    {
    public movieForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    private void exitButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Close form
        this.Close();
    }

    private void displayButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //create a variable named snack for snackForm
        snackForm snack = new snackForm();
        //show the form snack
        snack.ShowDialog();
    }
}
```

**Form2(snackForm):**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WongGregory9_part3ThreeForms
{
public partial class snackForm : Form
{
    //define varible ticket as 50
    int ticket = 50;
    //define varible twoTicket as 90
    int twoTickets = 90;
    //define varible threeTicket as 130
    int threeTickets = 130;
    //define varible popcorn as 65
    int popcorn = 65;
    //define varible soda as 30
    int soda = 30;
    //define varible chips as 40
    int chips = 40;
    //define varible ticketCost
    int ticketCost;
    //define varible snackCost
    int snackCost;
    //define varible totalCost;
    int totalCost;
    //create a variable named movie for movieForm
    movieForm movie = new movieForm();
    public snackForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void snackForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //if ticketRadioButton is checked then..
        if (movie.ticketRadioButton.Checked)
        {
            //ticketCost = ticket
            ticketCost = ticket;
        }
        //if ticketRadioButton2 is checked then..
        if (movie.ticketRadioButton2.Checked)
        {
            //ticketCost = twoTicket
            ticketCost = twoTickets;
        }
        //if ticketRadioButton3 is checked then..
        if (movie.ticketRadioButton3.Checked)
        {
            //ticketCost = threeTicket
            ticketCost = threeTickets;
        }
        //if popcornRadioButton is checked then..
        if (popcornRadioButton.Checked)
        {
            //snackCost = popcorn
            snackCost = popcorn;
        }
        //if sodaRadioButton is checked then..
        if (sodaRadioButton.Checked)
        {
            //snackCost = soda
            snackCost = soda;
        }
        //if chipsRadioButton is checked then..
        if (chipsRadioButton.Checked)
        {
            //snackCost = chips
            snackCost = chips;
        }
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //close form
        this.Close();
    }

    private void displayButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //create a variable named movie for movieForm
        displayForm display = new displayForm();
        //totalCosts equals ticketCost plus snackCost
        totalCost = ticketCost + snackCost;
        //display totalCost to displayLabel
        display.displayLabel.Text = totalCost.ToString();
        //show the dialog entered into displayForm
        display.ShowDialog();
    }
}
```

**Form3(displayForm):**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WongGregory9_part3ThreeForms
{
public partial class displayForm : Form
{
    public displayForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

Comment: `movieForm movie = new movieForm();` creates new instance of `movieForm` which is not related to instance which you have opened

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yup, two issues I can see, both in `snackForm`:

1. As per Sergey's comment, you are creating a new instance of movieForm, which doesn't know anything about the data on the original movieForm instance. You need to pass data from the original movieForm to your snackForm, in the same way as you pass the total cost from snackForm to displayForm.
2. You are checking the radio button selections in snackForm while the form is loading, i.e. before the user has had a chance to click them. Move these checks into `snackForm.displayButton_Click`

Comment: Thanks for the help!

Comment: Quick Question: How would I be able to transfer the "totalCost", "snackCost", and "ticketCost" from movieForm to snackForm?

Comment: From your description it sounds like you only need to pass `ticketCost` from `movieForm` to `snackForm`, since the other two are not determined until after the user has made a selection on the second form, Still, the way to do this is to pass them as arguments to the second form's constructor method, i.e. `snackForm snack = new snackForm(ticketCost);` Of course, you also have to declare this parameter in Form2's constructor definition. You can add as many parameters as you need, or declare a class that encapsulates the data fields and pass that between forms.